# Искусственный интелект С++

Tags: c++, искусственный-интеллект

Я собираюсь учиться ИИ на С++, но не знаю, где начать учиться. Кто может подсказать ресурсы для обучения ИИ и очень желательно сразу на С++?

Comment: а ваш ИИ чего уметь-то должен? есть не плохие статьи на хабре, можно на https://ru.coursera.org/ посмотреть. Но одним C++ вам тут не обойтись.

Comment: честно говоря я хочу научиться ИИ для олимпиад по спортивному программированию на ИИ и вот думаю как учиться, хотелось узнать мнение гиков в ИИ

Comment: В любом случии ИИ должна реашть какие-то задачи. Прочитайте что такое ИИ можно тут  Artifical Intelligence: A Modern Approach
Авторы Стюарт Рассел, Питер Норвиг. Реализация на языках  это уже второе дело в ИИ.

Comment: Хочу сразу дать один совет, но прошу не задавать мне дополнительных вопросов: забейте на эту тему. Вы потеряете много времени зря, и самым лучшим Вашим успехом будет то, что Вы станете отличным примером **ещё одного** человека, который разочаровался в данной теме. Знаю, что Вы не послушаетесь совета, но потом, когда разочаруетесь, вспомните, пожалуйста, что Вас предупреждали.

Comment: У Кнута есть интересная статья про альфа бета отсечение. Справишься с реализацией для шахмат или для "ход конем", будет отлично.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Могу посоветовать [Тим Джонс. Программирование искусственного интеллекта](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/19482525/), а если вас интересует олимпиадные задачи, то вам [сюда](http://codeforces.com/) или [сюда](https://code.google.com/codejam/). Google ведет интересные разработки нейронных сетей, но с применением Python, где-то видел англоязычную  [статью](https://www.tensorflow.org/). Почерпнуть интересную инфу [можно здесь](https://geektimes.ru/post/280992/) для воодушевления.